# Cannot find java.nio.file.Files

Tags: java

i need to import java.nio.file.* but cannot find the jar containing this package
I installed new version of jdk 1.8 but still i cannot import this package .Can anybody tell me the jar file containing this package.
Thanks

Comment: The JAR file containing this package is rt.jar in the JRE bin directory, but your problem is that you haven't adjusted the JRE or JDK used by your IDE, or possibly the version of Java you're using from the command line, depending on what exactly you're doing, which you haven't told us, and what exactly you mean by 'cannot import', ditto.

Comment: isnt `java.nio.file.Files` introduced in JDK 7 anyway? What were you upgrading from?

Answer (score -3):

I think the package want you to import is java input output.
Used this

```
import java.io.file.*;
```

Instead of

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```

Comment: nio is very much a thing

Comment: java.nio.file.Files is not the same as java.io.File!